# Error when debugging in code composer studio 12.3.0

Tags: c, microcontroller, code-composer

I'm trying to run some code in Code Composer Studio but this error keeps popping up for me when I debug and try to move through my code to run it. It's happened with other projects I've run but not all, which confuses me even more as to how it keeps popping up. It additionally opens up a bunch of other things

Can't find a source file at "C:\Users\ghost\workspace_v12\Lab Exam 1\Debug/../main.c"
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location

My main.c is still within my project folder and I'm not sure what else I can look at. The code itself isn't the problem, since I've run it on another person's laptop to no problem. The board I am using to code with is a MSP432P4111. The error happens around the Stop Watchdog comment. I had to change the stop watchdog command since it was triggering the error. Any ideas or helps would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <ti/devices/msp432p4xx/driverlib/driverlib.h>

/* Standard Includes */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
uint8_t colorcode;
const eUSCI_UART_ConfigV1 uartConfig=
{
 EUSCI_A_UART_CLOCKSOURCE_SMCLK,
 78,//BRDIV
 2, //UCxBRF
 0,//UCxBRS
 EUSCI_A_UART_NO_PARITY,
 EUSCI_A_UART_LSB_FIRST,
 EUSCI_A_UART_ONE_STOP_BIT,
 EUSCI_A_UART_MODE,
 EUSCI_A_UART_OVERSAMPLING_BAUDRATE_GENERATION

};
//Interrupt handler receives and echoes character typed in serial terminal
void EUSCIA0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        uint32_t status=UART_getEnabledInterruptStatus(EUSCI_A0_BASE);
        UART_clearInterruptFlag(EUSCI_A0_BASE,status);
        if (status & EUSCI_A_UART_RECEIVE_INTERRUPT_FLAG)
        {
        colorcode=UART_receiveData(EUSCI_A0_BASE);
        UART_transmitData(EUSCI_A0_BASE, colorcode);
        }

    }
void halfsecdelay()
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i=0;i<100000;i++);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Stop Watchdog  */
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_HOLD;

    // P1.2 and P1.3 are UART TXD and RXD. These pins must be put in special function mode
    GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionInputPin(GPIO_PORT_P1,GPIO_PIN2|GPIO_PIN3,GPIO_PRIMARY_MODULE_FUNCTION);
    //Sets DCO frequency at 12 MHz to get correct baud rate of 9600
    CS_setDCOCenteredFrequency(CS_DCO_FREQUENCY_12);
    MAP_UART_initModule(EUSCI_A0_BASE, &uartConfig);
    MAP_UART_enableModule(EUSCI_A0_BASE);
    UART_enableInterrupt(EUSCI_A0_BASE,EUSCI_A_UART_RECEIVE_INTERRUPT);
    Interrupt_enableInterrupt(INT_EUSCIA0);
    Interrupt_enableMaster();

    GPIO_setAsOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1); /*Green*/
    GPIO_setAsOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN2); /*Blue*/
    GPIO_setAsOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0); /*Refd*/

  /* Write in GPIO setup*/



    while(1)
    {
        if(colorcode=='R'){
            GPIO_setOutputHighOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0);
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1 | GPIO_PIN2);}
        else if(colorcode=='G'){
            GPIO_setOutputHighOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1);
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0 | GPIO_PIN2);}
        else if(colorcode=='B'){
            GPIO_setOutputHighOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN2);
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0 | GPIO_PIN1);}
        else if(colorcode=='r'){
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1 | GPIO_PIN2);
            GPIO_toggleOutputOnPin (GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0);
            int i;
            for (i = 100000; i > 0; i --);}
        else if(colorcode=='g'){
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0 | GPIO_PIN2);
            GPIO_toggleOutputOnPin (GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1);
            int i;
            for (i = 100000; i > 0; i --);}
        else if(colorcode=='b'){
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN1 | GPIO_PIN0);
            GPIO_toggleOutputOnPin (GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN2);
            int i;
            for (i = 100000; i > 0; i --);}
        else{
            GPIO_setOutputHighOnPin(GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN0 | GPIO_PIN1 | GPIO_PIN2);}
   }

}
```

I checked my project folder but it was still there, so it's not a main folder error. I tried moving the code to a different project and to a different project folder but the error still persisted. I'm a bit lost on what else to try

Comment: Please post the error as text instead of a picture. Your error says it can't find file `main.c` and it shows a path containing BOTH widows backslash separators `"\"` and Linux forward slash separators `"/"`. That will confuse any IDE. Find out where you are setting the project paths and make sure you are consistent in your use of directory separators. You will find the MSP432 driverlib to be very good. Make sure you have the driverlib reference manual and are using it.

Comment: You may also want to add what version of CCS you are using to your question.

Comment: I'm using 12.4.0 right now, I just reinstalled and am trying to run the program without going through the debug but I can't write in the terminal now for whatever reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: The terminal at the bottom of the IDE isn't normally writable as I recall, I've always just used it to look at the compiler output. Since you are using UART, you will want to connect to the MSP with PuTTY - that makes is easier to set the comm port, etc.. That will also give you read/write access to the MSP.

Comment: I downloaded Teraterm and got it to work. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Good! I'm glad you got it sorted. There is a lot to learn in programming the MSP. The driverlib makes it easier by giving you reasonably logical function names to work with instead of just using register addresses, and bit and mask values. Though there is a lot to learn to master driverlib. CCS does a good job configuring all parts of the build process to allow you to simply focus on your code (rather than spending the same amount of energy learning entry points, flash and linker scripts, include and library search paths, makefiles, etc..) Good luck with your coding.